# EditText showing 2 lines of text, instead of 1, despite of all properties set (only on Galax Tab 10.1, ICS)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, galaxy-tab

In my application, I have an EditText, which I want to show exactly 1 line of text. It works fine on most tablets (all running ICS), however, **the Galaxy Tab 10.1 displays long text in 2 lines instead of 1**.

I do have all properties set as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_chat_edit"
    ....
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minLines="1" />
```

I assume it's a bug in the Samsung firmware; can anybody confirm it? And eventually knows a workaround for it?

[image]

Comment: Can you please check actual properties of TextView after it's being inflated? I mean open HierarchyViewer and check singleLine, lines and maxLines props. I just want to check, is it just wrongly rendered, or someone overrides this properties, for example on system-level Styles (however your values must have priority over system-wide)

Comment: I tried to set the properties in code again, after the view's inflated: mEdtChatEdit.setLines(1);
        mEdtChatEdit.setMinLines(1);
        mEdtChatEdit.setMaxLines(1);
        mEdtChatEdit.setSingleLine(true); But doesn't help anything. Unfortunately I can't debug very well at the moment, cause I don't gave a Galaxy Tab here myself, I always need to send the apk to somebody who has it to take a look, which makes it a bit complicated right now :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually set the EditText height? Not the most elegant solution, but it would probably work.

Comment: It's an idea... - I will try it and let you know the feedback tomorrow -hope this workaround works.

Comment: Thanks, this workaround works. But I guess it's a bug in the Samsung firmware then.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I've not worked with the Tab before, but it seemed like a decent bet.